# why classes of tailwind are not working in react app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have set up tailwind in react app via npm based on what documentation says,there is no error but I see that only css reset codes of tailwind are working and no class works.
if you know what should I do, I'll appreciate it.

app.js :

```
import "./styles/output.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="bg-gray-200 text-xl border-4 border-red-500">
        hello world
      </h1>
      <p className="font-bold text-2xl m-5"> what are you doing ?</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions provided by tailwind? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: I found my problem, I hadnt added my files paths to the file tailwind.config.js, I added and now its working.

Comment: first I have to add the paths then use 'npm run start' again.